# How do we solve the ODE $(3-x)y' = y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve

$$(3-x)y' = y$$

What I did was
\begin{align*}
(3-x)\mathrm{d}y = y\mathrm{d}x & \Longleftrightarrow 
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{3-x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ln(y) = \ln(3-x) + C\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y = (3-x)c
\end{align*}

But the answer is $\dfrac{c}{3-x}$. How do you get it?

Comment: $\int\dfrac{dx}{1-x}=-\ln|1-x|+C,$ isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I spent far too long trying to solve this as I couldn't find any examples that match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to put $-$ with $\ln(3-x)$, that will come due to $$\int \frac{dx}{3-x}=-\ln(3-x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(3-x)y' = y$$
Substitute $u=3-x \implies du=-dx$:
$$u\dfrac {dy}{dx}=y$$
$$u\dfrac {dy}{du}\dfrac {du}{dx}=y$$
$$-u\dfrac {dy}{du}=y$$
$$-\dfrac {dy}{y}=\dfrac {du}u$$
Integrate.